# Images not displayed in certain Outlook 2013 messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, images, internet-explorer

In Outlook 2013, images are not displayed in some of my e-mails. This impacts the preview pane and full message view. At first, I get this info tip at the top of the message:
[image: Click here to download pictures.]

But when I click it and choose `Download Pictures` I get the familiar red X where the image should be in the e-mail:
[image: Evil Red X]

Today I got an e-mail that was entirely blank (no red X).  Above the blank message content window I was invited to view the message in a web browser:
[image]

I did and was able to view the message just fine.*

---

Now for the fun part.  <s>**The *only* messages I'm having this trouble with originate from a single domain.**</s> **EDIT:** I've discovered impacted messages sent from separate domains. I have Outlook 2013 on another computer using the same mailbox and *don't* have the problem on it.

**I've tried:**

- Added the senders' email addresses and as well as entire domain to Outlook's *Safe Senders* list.
- *Removed* all of these addresses from the *Safe Senders* list, then clicked the **Click here to download pictures** prompt.
- Disabled then re-enabled the **Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail messages or RSS items** in the Trust Center.

  - *EDIT:* I've also left this setting disabled completely and the pictures still don't display.
- Deleted all occurrences of my problem domain from the Registry (the only ones I found were in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\DOMStorage`)
- Added the problem domain to Internet Explorer's *Trusted Sites*

I know I could try deleting and re-creating my Outlook profile, but I have a ton of customizations that would make that option even more painful than continuing to put up with this.

What else can I try to get these images to display?

**Update:**
When I try to right-click the red X image placeholder and choose *Save as Picture...* I get a normal Save As dialog box but when I click **Save** I get the message *There was an error saving the file.*

**Update 2:**
I viewed the Source for one of these messages and saved the resulting HTML code as an HTML file, then opened it in Internet Explorer.  The missing image was there!

**Update 3:**

1. I broke down and tried another Outlook profile. *The problem persists.*
2. I tried deleting Internet Explorers Browsing History (Tools > Internet options > General tab > Delete... > de-select `Preserve Favorites website data` and select all other checkboxes). No joy.
3. Thinking perhaps I'm crazy and the images simply don't exist on the server where they're stored, I logged into my mailbox using Outlook Web Access. *The pictures are displayed correctly.*
4. **I've discovered an e-mail from another Internet domain that isn't properly displaying images.**
5. While running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) I've selected the `Download Pictures` option on a message. There's a lot of registry activity just switching between Outlook and ProcMon, but I'm pretty certain this setting is stored in the `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046\11020434` value. Problem is, that value is large, encoded, and seems to store many settings, not just this one.

<sub>*I moved the message to my Junk Mail folder and confirmed there was more to the message, so I assume some HTML magic was (trying) to replace the text with an image.</sub>

---

**Update 4:**

This is what the message **does** look like in Outlook:
[image]

This is what the message **should** look like:
[image]

#### Here's the code of one of these messages in `.EML` format:

```
Received: from p02c11m011.mxlogic.net (208.65.144.245) by
 remote.removed.com (192.168.25.11) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id
 14.1.438.0; Thu, 13 Nov 2014 12:14:18 -0500
Received: from unknown [64.111.23.181] (EHLO ccb-out-10.ccbchurch.com)  by
 p02c11m011.mxlogic.net(mxl_mta-8.2.0-0) over TLS secured channel   with ESMTP
 id bf6e4645.0.7002.00-2299.13545.p02c11m011.mxlogic.net (envelope-from
 <notifications@ccbchurch.com>);    Thu, 13 Nov 2014 10:14:35 -0700 (MST)
Received: from localhost (ccb-out-10 [127.0.0.1])   by ccb-out-10.ccbchurch.com
 (Postfix) with ESMTP id BE8292DD0138   for <removed@removed.com>; Thu,
 13 Nov 2014 10:14:34 -0700 (MST)
To: =?UTF-8?B?TmF0ZSBCYWNodGVs?= <removed@removed.com>
From: =?UTF-8?B?TmF0ZSBCYWNodGVs?= <notifications@ccbchurch.com>
Date: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 10:14:34 -0700
Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?TmF0ZSBCYWNodGVs?= <removed@removed.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?VEVTVCBFbWFpbCBmb3IgU3VwZXJVc2Vy?=
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:fbl@ccbchurch.com>
Sender: Church Community Builder <notifications@ccbchurch.com>
Message-ID: <29759338-192.168.0.22-20141113101434@ccbchurch.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Processed-By: Rebuild v2.0-0
X-AnalysisOut: [8wgzMAA:9 a=EnciHZ9zj99YinxO:21 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10]
X-Spam: [F=0.2340425532; B=0.500(0); spf=0.500; STSI=0.500(8); STSM=0.500(8); CM=0.500; CY=0.500; MH=0.550(2014111305); S=0.200(2014051901); SC=]
X-MAIL-FROM: <notifications@ccbchurch.com>
X-SOURCE-IP: [64.111.23.181]
Return-Path: notifications@ccbchurch.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SVRSBS01.removed.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PRD: ccbchurch.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SenderIdResult: SoftFail
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 1
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Antispam-Report: DV:3.3.14115.477;SID:SenderIDStatus SoftFail;OrigIP:208.65.144.245
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----=_NextPart_57923364.725073226561"
X-Msg2Mime: True
X-Msg2Mime-Creation-Time: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 12:15:01 -0500
X-Msg2Mime-Message-Delivery-Time: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 12:14:18 -0500
X-Msg2Mime-Client-Submit-Time: Thu, 13 Nov 2014 12:14:34 -0500

------=_NextPart_57923364.725073226561
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

     
TEST Email for SuperUser     
     
     Crossroads Evangelical Free Church Online Community Participant
Message from REMOVED

This is a test email.  There should be an image in the footer of this
e-mail.      
     
This message is from Crossroads Evangelical Free Church. Crossroads
Evangelical Free Church treats your personal information with the utmost
care. To report abuse related to this email, please contact our office
at (123) 123-9999.

Unsubscribe
<https://crossroads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_settings_communication.
php?id=39&tk=9A1RJDN6SFVUFB7DE648E4BU5R4DUUUV>  or change your
preferences
<https://crossroads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_settings_communication.
php?id=39&tk=9A1RJDN6SFVUFB7DE648E4BU5R4DUUUV>  for receiving emails
like this one. 

 <https://cdn3.ccbchurch.com/1/images/email/logo.png> 
     

------=_NextPart_57923364.725073226561
Content-Type: text/rtf;
 charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\fromhtml1 \fbidis \deff0{\fonttbl=0A=0D{\f0\fswiss\=
fcharset0 Arial;}=0A=0D{\f1\fmodern Courier New;}=0A=0D{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 =
Symbol;}=0A=0D{\f3\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier New;}=0A=0D{\f4\fswiss\fcharse=
t0 Arial;}}=0A=0D{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red242\=
green242\blue242;\red51\green51\blue102;\red255\green255\blue255;\red51\gre=
en51\blue51;\red102\green102\blue102;}=0A=0D\uc1\pard\plain\deftab360 \f0\f=
s24 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag243 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transi=
tional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag1=
9 <html>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag34 <head>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag1 \par }=0A=0D{\*\html=
tag177 <title>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag241 TEST Email for SuperUser}=0A=0D{\*\html=
tag185 </title>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag1 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag41 </head>}=0A=0D=
{\*\htmltag2 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag50 <body bgcolor=3D"#f2f2f2" style=3D"b=
ackground-color: #f2f2f2; margin: 0; padding: 0;">}\htmlrtf \viewkind5=0A=
=0D{\*\background {\shp{\*\shpinst{\sp{\sn fillColor}{\sv 15921906}}{\sp{\s=
n fFilled}{\sv 1}}}}}\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag24=
0 \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" ce=
llspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" bgcolor=3D"#f2f2f2">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plai=
n \f0\fs24 \highlight2 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrt=
f0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td align=3D"center">}\htm=
lrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"600" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpa=
dding=3D"0" class=3D"back">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D=
{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\h=
tmltag148 <td align=3D"center">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par=
 }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrt=
f }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"600" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpa=
dding=3D"0" class=3D"main">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D=
{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\h=
tmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td height=3D"27">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td=
>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=
=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrt=
f\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\h=
tmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td class=
=3D"header" align=3D"left" height=3D"60" width=3D"600" bgcolor=3D"#333366" =
style=3D"-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;=
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;=
 border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 5px;">}\htmlrtf {\hi=
ghlight3 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \=
tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \html=
rtf}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellp=
adding=3D"0">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 =
<tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td =
align=3D"center">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\ht=
mltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \t=
ab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"95%" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpa=
dding=3D"15">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 =
<tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td =
class=3D"headertext" style=3D"font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; text-shad=
ow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <fo=
nt color=3D"#ffffff" face=3D"Arial">}\htmlrtf {\cf4 \f4 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*=
\htmltag84 <b>}\htmlrtf {\b \htmlrtf0 TEST Email for SuperUser=0A=0D{\*\htm=
ltag92 </b>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </font>}\htmlrtf }\htm=
lrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag=
4 \par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \t=
ab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf=
0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </table>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </td>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par=
 }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \t=
ab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </table>}\html=
rtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </td>}=0A=0D{\=
*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \t=
ab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\=
htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmlt=
ag148 <td bgcolor=3D"#ffffff" class=3D"maincontent" style=3D"font-family: A=
rial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; color: #333333;">}\htmlrtf {\hi=
ghlight4 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \=
tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \html=
rtf}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag96 <table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" cellp=
adding=3D"0">}\htmlrtf {\pard\plain \f0\fs24 \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \=
par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td height=3D"28">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmlt=
ag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\ta=
b \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag8=
4 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrt=
f\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\h=
tmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td width=
=3D"28">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlr=
tf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 =
\par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td class=3D=
"mainbar" align=3D"left" valign=3D"top">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\html=
tag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <font face=3D"Arial" c=
olor=3D"#333333" style=3D"font-size: 12px;">}\htmlrtf {\f4 \cf5 \htmlrtf0 =
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab =
\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab =
}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag68 <p style=3D"color: #ababab; margin-top: 0; padding-bot=
tom: 5px; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal;">}=0A=
=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }Crossro=
ads Evangelical Free Church Online Community Participant=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 =
\par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=
=0D{\*\htmltag116 <br>}\htmlrtf \line=0A=0D\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <=
span style=3D"font-weight: bold; color: #999; font-family: Arial; font-size=
: 13px;">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 Message from REMOVED=0A=0D{\*\htmltag156=
 </span>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf }\htm=
lrtf0 \htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0=0A=0D\htmlrtf \par=0A=0D\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\ht=
mltag72 </p>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \=
tab }{\*\htmltag64}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf {\f4 \cf5 \htmlrtf0 This is=
 a test email.=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlrtf0  There shou=
ld be an image in the footer of this e-mail.=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }\htmlr=
tf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \=
tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </font>}\htmlrtf }\=
htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \=
tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag252 </td=
>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \ta=
b \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td width=
=3D"28">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlr=
tf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 =
\par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }{\*\htmltag72}\htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\h=
tmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td height=
=3D"24">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlr=
tf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 =
\par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </tabl=
e>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </td>}=
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=
=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td height=3D"80" class=3D"footer" align=3D"left" style=
=3D"font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; color: #666;"=
>}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \ta=
b \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <=
font face=3D"Arial" size=3D"1" color=3D"#666666">}\htmlrtf {\f4 \fs16 \cf6 =
\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab =
\tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag68 <p style=
=3D"font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; color: #666; =
margin: 10px 0 0;">}This message is from Crossroads Evangelical Free Church=
. Crossroads Evangelical Free Church treats your personal information with =
the utmost care. To report abuse related to this email, please contact our =
office at (123) 123-9999.=0A=0D{\*\htmltag116 <br>}\htmlrtf \line=0A=0D\htm=
lrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag116 <br>}\htmlrtf \line=0A=0D\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htm=
ltag84 <a style=3D"color: #545454; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-=
style: dotted; border-bottom-color: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-fa=
mily: Arial; font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal;" href=3D"https://crossro=
ads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_settings_communication.php?id=3D39&amp;tk=
=3D9A1RJDN6SFVUFB7DE648E4BU5R4DUUUV" target=3D"_blank">}\htmlrtf {\field{\*=
\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://crossroads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_setting=
s_communication.php?id=3D39&tk=3D9A1RJDN6SFVUFB7DE648E4BU5R4DUUUV" \\n}}{\f=
ldrslt\cf1\ul \htmlrtf0 Unsubscribe\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag92 </a>} or =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 <a style=3D"color: #545454=
; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-colo=
r: #545454; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; fon=
t-weight: normal;" href=3D"https://crossroads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_=
settings_communication.php?id=3D39&amp;tk=3D9A9TJCN6RFVUZB7DE898D4TU5N4DUYU=
V" target=3D"_blank">}\htmlrtf {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://crossr=
oads-efc.ccbchurch.com/individual_settings_communication.php?id=3D39&tk=3D9=
A9TJCN6RFVUZB7DE898D4TU5N4DUYUV" \\n}}{\fldrslt\cf1\ul \htmlrtf0 change you=
r preferences\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag92 </=
a>} for receiving emails like this one.=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }\htmlrtf  \=
htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \=
tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 \htmlrtf\par}\h=
tmlrtf0=0A=0D\htmlrtf \par=0A=0D\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </p>}=0A=0D{\=
*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \t=
ab \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </font>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \pa=
r }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \=
tab \tab }{\*\htmltag64}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 <img src=3D=
"https://cdn3.ccbchurch.com/1/images/email/logo.png" alt=3D"Church Communit=
y Builder">}\htmlrtf  {\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK "https://cdn3.ccbchurch.=
com/1/images/email/logo.png"}}{\fldrslt\cf1\ul }}\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmlta=
g4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag252 </td>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\html=
tag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab }{\*\htmltag72}\htm=
lrtf\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag64 <tr>}\h=
tmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag148 <td height=
=3D"60">}\htmlrtf {\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 &nbsp;}\htmlrtf \'a0\htmlr=
tf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag156 </td>}\htmlrtf }\tab \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag4 =
\par }\htmlrtf  \htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag84 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab \tab \tab \tab }\htmlrtf\par}\htmlrtf0=0A
=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </tabl=
e>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </td>}=
=0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab \tab=
 \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </tr>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </table>}\htmlrtf }\h=
tmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag248 </td>}=0A=0D{\*\htmlt=
ag0 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag240 \tab \tab \tab \tab }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag72 </t=
r>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag104 </table>}\htmlrtf }\htmlrtf0 =0A=0D{\*\htmltag0 \pa=
r }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag58 </body>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag2 \par }=0A=0D{\*\htmltag27=
 </html>}=0A=0D{\*\htmltag3 \par }}
------=_NextPart_57923364.725073226561--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that your pictures are served over an `https:` link (which is good).  This [slipstick.com](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/picture-placeholders-displaying-outlook-email-messages/) article suggests your problem can be solved by disabling the `Do not save encrypted pages to disk` option in Internet Explorer's Advanced settings dialog:

> In IE go to **Internet Options-Advanced**; look under Security for **Do not
>   save encrypted files to disk**. Untick this setting and Apply. Restart
>   Outlook and you should be fixed.

Microsoft actually [recommends](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/07/downloads-and-flash-fail-when-do-not-save-encrypted-pages-to-disk-is-set.aspx) that you not enable the `Do not save encrypted pages to disk` (the default is disabled).

Comment: Bingo. That's the problem.  I suspect it got changed from the default of not enabled by the use of an IE10 Group Policy Preference in my domain as noted to be a problem by the commenter `kwacky1` on this [Microsoft USGCB Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2010/10/06/sticking-with-well-known-and-proven-solutions.aspx).